# Как сделать  новую вкладку на C#?

Tags: c#

Создал браузер простенький хочу что бы можно было добавлять новые вкладки. Знаю что делается через TabControl но какой код вписать так и не разобрался.

Comment: Не бывает просто «на C#» — графические библиотеки в язык не встроены. WPF, WinForms, GTK#?

Answer (score 2):

[TabControl.TabPages.Add](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/btz4twwd.aspx) - Вы это ищете, видимо.

Answer (score 1):

Я делаю так. Создаю вкладку и в нее вставляю RichTextBox. В новую вкладку потом добавляю все что мне нужно, в моем случае текст. Вот код

```
private TabPage CreateTabPage(string filename)
        {
            TabPage tabPage = new TabPage();
            RichTextBox textBox = new RichTextBox();

            FileInfo info = new FileInfo(filename);
            if (info.Exists)
            {
                // 
                // tabPage
                // 
                tabPage.Name = info.Name;
                tabPage.Padding = new System.Windows.Forms.Padding(3);
                tabPage.BackColor = this.BackColor;
                tabPage.ForeColor = this.ForeColor;

                tabPage.Text = info.Name;
                tabPage.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
                tabPage.Tag = info;
                tabPage.ToolTipText = info.FullName;
                tabPage.ImageIndex = 0;
              
                // 
                // textBox
                // 
                textBox.Multiline = true;
                textBox.Name = info.Name;
                textBox.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
                textBox.ScrollBars = RichTextBoxScrollBars.Vertical;
                textBox.SelectionAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Left;
                textBox.Font = new Font("Times new roman", 16);
                textBox.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.None;
                textBox.TextChanged += TextBox_TextChanged;
                textBox.TabStop = false;
                textBox.Parent = tabPage;
                textBox.ForeColor = textBox.Parent.ForeColor;
                textBox.BackColor = textBox.Parent.BackColor;

                tabPage.Controls.Add(textBox);
                this.tabControl.Controls.Add(tabPage);
                this.tabControl.SelectedTab = tabPage;

                OnStatusTextChanged?.Invoke(this, "Create New TabPage " + info.Name);
//                this.toolStripStatusLabel_Information.Text = "Create New TabPage " + info.Name;
                return tabPage;
            }

            return null;
        }
```